# how i can open activity array class name in list-view

Tags: java, android

i have n class items auto generate like by java in window i want use this class in my app , how i can open class activity by name in list view ? android can do it by implements

```
  import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private static final Class[] CLASSES = new Class[]{
            a.class,
            a1.class,
            a2.class,
            a3.class,
            a4.class,
            a5.class,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CLASSES);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes is very easy

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private static final Class[] CLASSES = new Class[]{
            a.class,
            a1.class,
            a2.class,
            a3.class,
            a4.class,
            a5.class
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CLASSES);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Class clicked = CLASSES[position];
        startActivity(new Intent(this, clicked));
    }

    private static class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Class> {
        private Context mContext;
        private Class[] mClasses;

        private MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, Class[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            mContext = context;
            mClasses = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
            }
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(mClasses[position].getSimpleName());

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/CustomRelativeLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        style="@style/CustomLogoImageView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Context` that you passed in your adapter and call `context.startActivity(new Intent(context,className))`.

If you want to launch the `Activity` from within your adapter, you'll need to set an `onClickListener()` on the buttons in your adapter item layout files. If your entire list item can be selected, you can implement `OnItemClickListener` in your activity and launch the activity indexed in the position that was clicked and just use `startActivity(new Intent(this,CLASSES[i]))` where i is the position of the clicked item.